# Installation of Privileged Helpertool fails - kSMErrorDomainFramework

Tags: cocoa, security, authorization

In my app am I using the code from the EvenBetterAuthorizationSample, except that of the AppDelegate and the .xib-file. I have equalized the Project- and Target-settings. Also the adjustments of the Readme-file are done. The sample installs the privileged tool, but in my app SMJobBless fails with error kSMErrorDomainFramework code 4, which means an authorization right problem. But I can't find the reason/solution. Whatever I tried it didn't help.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Could you please check your /Applications/Utilities/Console.app and see what it prints during the SMJobBless failure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing my answer here anyway, since it fixed the exact same issue for me.

It seems that the certificate validation code is for **Developer ID** type of certificates and is not valid for development certificates. I used the iOS certificate validation string from [Technical Note TN2319](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/tn2319/_index.html) and it also worked perfectly for my Mac developer certificates. So the process after downloading **EvenBetterAuthorizationSample** was:

In files *App/App-Info.plist* and *App-Sandboxed/XPCService/XPCService-Info.plist*:

```
anchor apple generic and identifier "com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.HelperTool" and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] /* exists */ or certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = SKMME9E2Y8)
```

should be modified into

```
anchor apple generic and identifier "com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.HelperTool" and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] /* exists */ and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] /* exists */ or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] /* exists */) and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = SKMME9E2Y8
```

In file *HelperTool/HelperTool-Info.plist*:

```
anchor apple generic and identifier "com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.App" and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] /* exists */ or certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = SKMME9E2Y8)
```

should be modified into

```
anchor apple generic and identifier "com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.App" and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] /* exists */ and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] /* exists */ or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] /* exists */) and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = SKMME9E2Y8
```

and also

```
anchor apple generic and identifier "com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.XPCService" and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] /* exists */ or certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = SKMME9E2Y8)
```

should be modified into

```
anchor apple generic and identifier "com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.XPCService" and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] /* exists */ and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] /* exists */ or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] /* exists */) and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = SKMME9E2Y8
```

After this you still need to modify the **SKMME9E2Y8** to your organizational unit in all these four places. It is quite easy to check this from Keychain Access by selecting the Mac Developer certificate and selecting Get Info from the right click menu. The correct value is under **Subject Name** after **Organizational Unit**. Doing all this everything should work smoothly.

**Edit:**

Please note that this is still kind of a hack, for proper app distribution you would need the **Developer ID** certificate available from Apple developer website. Using that certificate for development is a bit of overkill and maybe not even feasible for multiple developers, so using the hack above should get anyone started.

Comment: I changed that to a private key, what I Tested/used for several other projects and it worked. In anyway I'll check that in the next days. Thx for your answer.